# Centering an App in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've chosen Landscape only for my view in 800w x 480h available space. I want my app to be 600 (w) by 240 (h), absolutely sized. <sub>(There is a long story as to why this is, but it ain't gonna change - I don't want or need to fill all of the available space and need absolute sizing)</sub>.

How can I center the app horizontally and vertically so that is its CenterX/Y is the same as the available space's CenterX/Y. I've tried `VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"` on both `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage/>` as well as `<Grid/>` and `<Canvas/>` tags - none of this works. Any thoughts on how I be able to center my app on screen?

Comment: @Matt Lacey: Can't, it's a product for a client and NDAs are in place.

Comment: I was just curios for the business case for creating somehting  that looks so different to everything else on the phone and doesn't make use of all the available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with margins on the main grid:

```
Margin="100,120"
```

100 = (800-600)/2

120 = (480-240)/2

Comment: Hmmm...that's an interesting approach. It may just be the one I use. Will stand by for other answers for a bit and if nothing comes in that is part of the framework, will accept this one.

Comment: No problem. I agree it's not a pretty solution but it has the merit of being simple.

Comment: Definetely, it has that going for it, easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a grid, and nest a grid inside with Width="600" and Height="240", with HorizontalAlign="Center" and VerticalAlign set to the counterpart?